# How to create a single click event for multiple buttons in .NET MAUI

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I have created a simple application where I have many buttons and I want to create just one click event for all the buttons, so what's the logic in xamarin forms or .net maui?

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you have two buttons just like this:

```
<Button Clicked="EventClickedHandler"/>
<Button Clicked="EventClickedHandler"/>
```

Now just add the Class id inside these button controls like this

```
<Button Clicked="EventClickedHandler" ClassId="1"/>
<Button Clicked="EventClickedHandler" ClassId="2"/>
```

Then inside the click event handler you can write the following code:

```
private void EventClickedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var button = (Button)sender;
    var classId = button.ClassId;
    // This will give you the value / classId of your button which you'll press
    DisplayAlert("Hi", classId.ToString(), "Alright");
}
```

Comment: Thank you man! I got it. I've actually craete an application just like a calculator and your code works like a charm. Thanks once again.